# Customize the inputs for paypal payment

Tags: php, html, paypal

I am using the paypal form below. I made some changes so that I could get some custom input fields. I want a field name quantity or numbers which will be a dropdown menu. When the user selects one option from it, and clicks on buy now, he/she will be redirected to the paypal page and the price will be displayed with the multiplication of actual price with quantity.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">  
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="dsfddgdr@gmail.com">
                Ad Type:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $product; ?>"> <br/> 
                <!-- <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">   -->
                <!-- <input type="text" name="Ad_Type" value="1"> -->
                Price:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="amount" value="$<?php echo $price; ?>"> 
                 <strong>Which tutorial are you donating for?</strong><br />  
                <select name="item_quantity">  
                  <option value="1">1</option>  
                  <option value="2">2</option>  
                  <option value="3">3</option>  
                </select>   
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="0">  
                <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">  
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">  
                <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">  
                <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">  
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="domain.com/success.php?ad_id=<?php echo $ad_id; ?>&user_id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>&ad_level=<?php echo $ad_level; ?>&ad_duration=<?php echo $ad_duration; ?>">  

                <input type="image" src="paypal_checkout_EN.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">  
                <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">  
            </form>
```

[image]

I am stuck. It is showing me the select field but how do I make it to work in the paypal page??

Answer (score 2):

The PayPal page is only for displaying the provided information and cannot be used to change the amount / quantity etc.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Change `item_quantity` to just `quantity`.